# How do I programatically make a Liferay Portlet go into Full Screen Mode

Tags: java, portlet, liferay

I'm sure it's an easy thing, but I can't find it anywhere. How do I programatically make a portlet inside of Liferay go into Full Screen Mode. eg: the equivalent of clicking on the maximise button, but in code rather than having to make the user manually click that button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set window state in the action phase. ActionResponse interface has method setWindowState().

You cannot change the state in the render phase -- try to imagine what would happened if two or more portlets decided to maximize themself.

- [method setWindowState()](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/StateAwareResponse.html#setWindowState%28javax.portlet.WindowState%29)
- [class WindowState](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/WindowState.html)

Answer (score 1):

Inside `processAction(..)`:

```
actionResponse.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
```

inside `doView(..)`:

```
renderRequest.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: you cannot set the WindowState in a RenderRequest. This is only possible in a ActionRequest/Response...unfortunately